# Characters Transform in Python

Tags: python, character, transform, python-2.x

I'm processing some problems involve Chinese characters matching using Python, how to transform coding type like `'\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe5\xb0\xbd\xe7\x84\xb6'` into type like `'\u53ef\u80fd'`, `'u4f1a'`?

Can I transform single words between these two types where I want to?

Comment: You need to know the encoding used. My _guess_ is that it's UTF-8, and your first string decodes to `u'\u4e0d\u5c3d\u7136'`, which looks Chinese to me. You should also mention the Python version you are using because Python 2 and Python 3 handle Unicode differently.

Comment: Great. But do you know the encoding of your data?

Comment: You need to call the `str.decode()` method with the correct encoding. Eg, `'\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe5\xb0\xbd\xe7\x84\xb6'.decode('utf8')`. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I get it !